# Monthly Growth - Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need your help again. I need to calculate the monthly growth for the trips.

The query that I have written is below:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE (stoptime)) AS Year, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE (stoptime)) AS Month,
    COUNT(bikeid) AS Trips,
    ROUND(100* (COUNT(bikeid)- LAG(COUNT(bikeid),1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY 'Year' ORDER BY 'Year', 'Month'))/lag(COUNT(bikeid),1) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY 'Year' ORDER BY 'Year', 'Month')) ||'%' AS growth
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
WHERE end_station_name LIKE '%University%'
GROUP BY Year, Month
ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
```

However, the query below cannot give me the right output. The output from the query above as below:

[image: 1]

I do not know which part of my query is wrong. Kindly help me with this.

My desired output example:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: what is your desired output

Answer (score 0):

and if you are calculating monthly growth, why aren't you calculating the number of trips in eahc month :

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE (stoptime)) AS YEAR
    , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE (stoptime)) AS MONTH
    , COUNT(bikeid) AS Trips
    , ROUND(100* (COUNT(bikeid)- LAG(COUNT(bikeid),1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY 'Year','Month' ORDER BY 'Year', 'Month' desc))
                 /lag(COUNT(bikeid),1) OVER (PARTITION BY 'Year','Month' ORDER BY 'Year', 'Month' desc)) ||'%' AS growth
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
WHERE end_station_name LIKE '%University%'
GROUP BY Year, Month
ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
```

Comment: isn't my query calculate for each month? in the table, there are several years and months.

Comment: my desired output example:

Year    Month Trips Growth
2016 12 1750 
2016 11 1500 -14%
2016 10 1000 -33%

Comment: did you try my query ?

Comment: Yes. I've tried your query above, but the outcome quite similar to my previous one